# Losing Access Token when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

So I have a javascript file that routes to pages, and the 'Home' page loses the access token and becomes a null value whenever the page is refreshed. How do I keep it from losing the token when the page is refreshed. Because right now, if I press the refresh button on the home page, it will lose the access token until I press logout and log back in.

```
var Spotify = require('spotify-web-api-js');
var spotifyApi = new Spotify();

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    const params = this.getHashParams(); //tokens saved here
    const token = params.access_token;
    if (token) {
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(token);
    }
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: token ? true : false,
      atoken: token, //access token
    };
    console.log(spotifyApi.getAccessToken())
    //localStorage.setItem(token, this.state.atoken)
  }

    getHashParams() { //gets users refresh and access token
      var hashParams = {};
      var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
          q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
      e = r.exec(q)
      while (e) {
         hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
         e = r.exec(q);
      }
      return hashParams;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className='App'>
          <Route exact path = '/' component= {Home}/>
          <Route path= '/playlist' component = {Playlist}/>
        </div>
      </Router>

    ); 
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You're storing things in LocalStorage, but I don't see you pull those values back out.

Comment: Oh yeah, i was toying with the localStorage to see how it worked, my code doesn't really use it and i forgot to remove that line before posting this question. I wasn't sure how the scope of localStorage worked. Like if I set the variable in the localStorage in the parent class, 'App', I'm not sure how I'd pass it down to the 'Home' class @Evert

Comment: When you refresh your page, the entire memory of your application is wiped clean. So to retain something (like tokens) you need to store it somewhere. LocalStorage is the perfect place.

Comment: @Evert yes but lets say I store the access token in Local Storage in this parent class 'App', will the child component 'Home' still have access to that same localStorage when I do localStorage.get()? Because I'm not understanding how the scope of localStorage works

Comment: The scope of LocalStorage is per domain. Any tab, any component will have global access to the same store